# Thumb assembly under Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, thumb

I'm trying to get object file (`.o`) on Ubuntu using `arm-linux-gnueabi-as`. Here's my set of instructions:

```
.thumb

.globl _start
_start:

cmp r0, r2
VST1.32 {D16-D17}, [R2]
```

When I run: `arm-linux-gnueabi-as  -mthumb thumb.s -o thumb.o`
I'm getting this error:
`` thumb.s:7: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `vst1.32 {D16-D17},[R2]' ``

I've tried using parameters `-mcpu=<cpu name>` and `-march=<arch name>` like `-mcpu=cortex-m4` and `-march=armv7-m` but I'm still getting the same error.

Is there any way to simulate another CPU to get thumb instruction set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `-mfpu=neon`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this for x64 arch? Is there ```arm64-linux-gnueabi-as``` available or it can be done with parameters?

Comment: Also I've noticed this ```Error: unexpected character `w' in type specifier Error: bad instruction `mov.w r0,r1'```. When I use ```ldr``` instead of ```mov.w``` it works fine.

Comment: Yes, there is aarch64 version of binutils too.

Comment: which architecture should I use for ```mov.w``` regarding this problem: ```Error: bad instruction `mov.w r0,r1'```

Comment: What do you want that to do? movw/mov.w only work with constants as far as I know. Use normal `mov r0,r1`